# How to make fake proxy Import library

Tags: c, gcc, ld, binutils

I remember finding *.a library that doesn't contain any object but instead a list libraries (as a plain text?), something like: `-liconv -lm`

So that when gcc encounter it, both library will be searched for linking.

Is there such trick? pretty sure it was working that time, but I don't know how to make it now.

Comment: You're perhaps looking for `libtool` and `.la` files!

Comment: if I recall the file was system libraries (part of the compiler build by someone) so there is no .la files there. and I tested it directly against gcc not via makefile/libtool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your linker from binutils?  binutils `ld` supports `.a` files as [implicit linker scripts](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Implicit-Linker-Scripts.html):

> If you specify a linker input file which the linker can not recognize as an object file or an archive file, it will try to read the file as a linker script. If the file can not be parsed as a linker script, the linker will report an error.

A linker script does not have to be complicated, it can be as simple as this (for glibc's `libc.so`):

```
/* GNU ld script.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
GROUP ( …/libc.so.6 …/libc_nonshared.a AS_NEEDED ( …/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ) )
```

Or you can just [use `INPUT` to delegate things to `ld`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/File-Commands.html):

> If you use ‘`INPUT (-lfile)`’, ld will transform the name to `libfile.a`, as with the command line argument ‘`-l`’.

Comment: yes it's binutils, but I don't think it is complicated linker script, I don't remember get strange message such `treating as linker script`. That time my impression was "Whoever make this lib certainly tricked gcc!"

Comment: I don't think you get a warning, and linker scripts can actually be quite short.  All that section placement stuff is optional.

Comment: Ahh you're right it must be that, must be forgot about the messages

Comment: it was oneliner text `INPUT(-liconv -lm)` saved as libxx.a! thanks